# SSL Library Error: 336117909 error:1408C095:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_FINISHED:digest check failed

Tags: openssl

I am getting below error during handshake

```
[error] SSL Library Error: 336117909 error:1408C095:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_FINISHED:digest check failed
[error] [client client_ip] Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by  client!?
[error] [client client_ip] Re-negotiation request failed
[error] SSL Library Error: 336117909 error:1408C095:SSL    
routines:SSL3_GET_FINISHED:digest check failed
```

below is httpd.conf setting

```
            <VirtualHost ip:443>

            Header always set P3P "CP=\"NON DSP COR CURa TIA\""

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
            RewriteRule /_redirect....:%{QUERY_STRING}} [R]

            #  Security Parameters - Using Rewrite to disable cross-site-scripting attacks
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
            RewriteRule .* - [F]

            #  General setup for the virtual host
            DocumentRoot "/path_to_doc_root"
            ServerName server_name
            ServerAdmin admin@server_name
            ErrorLog "path to error log"
            CustomLog "path to custom log" combined

            # SSL setup of the virtual host

            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
            SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:RC4:MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
            SSLHonorCipherOrder on

            SSLCertificateFile "/path of cert file"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile "path of key"
            SSLCertificateChainFile "path of Full_.crt"

            SSLCACertificateFile /path of ca-bundle.crt
            SSLOptions +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate

            <Location /secure >
                   ..
                   ..
                    SSLRequireSSL
                    SSLVerifyClient require
                    SSLVerifyDepth 10
                    SSLOptions +ExportCertData
            </Location>

            </VirtualHost>
```

Above setting was working fine. But after client upgrade there .net framework (not sure which version), above error start coming. I am not sure why this error is coming and which step of handshake is getting failed. I did google but could not find any explanation.

Can someone please explain about the above error and what should I do to rectify this.

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks....